# Using MacPorts build of PHP causes Apache to SEGV

Tags: apache-http-server, php, macports, macos-ventura

I have successfully added PHP to the built-in Apache on Mac OS Ventura (on Intel), however it's an old build of PHP 7.  My problem is that when I try to use the latest version as built using MacPorts I get a segmentation violation.  In both attempts they are signed, as required.

I first put it in a custom location `/etc/apache2/modules/mod_php80.so` and signed it.

```
root@vger:/etc/apache2/modules(28)+>- /usr/sbin/httpd
[Sun Oct 01 19:58:56.982055 2023] [so:notice] [pid 6449] AH06662: Allowing module loading process to continue for module at /etc/apache2/modules/mod_php80.so because module signature matches authority "Philip Kearns\xe2\x80\x99s CA" specified in LoadModule directive
Segmentation fault
root@vger:/etc/apache2/modules(29)+>-
```

I tried using it in its original location:

```
root@vger:/etc/apache2/modules(33)+>- /usr/sbin/httpd
[Sun Oct 01 20:02:56.564926 2023] [so:notice] [pid 6600] AH06662: Allowing module loading process to continue for module at /opt/local/lib/apache2/modules/mod_php80.so because module signature matches authority "Philip Kearns\xe2\x80\x99s CA" specified in LoadModule directive
Segmentation fault
root@vger:/etc/apache2/modules(34)+>-
```

Has anyone seen such behaviour elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite obvious really: the Mac Ports module is built against its own Apache (`/opt/sbin/httpd`) so it would never work for the built-in macOS Apache.